# Using the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus to solve a first order ODE

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, proof-verification

I'm working through *A First Course in Differential Equations* by Zill to get a head start for next semester, and I've come to this method of finding a solution for cases of separation of variables that result in non-elementary integrals. The text does not go into the details behind the solution, and though I have a general grasp on the formula, my intuition is still lacking full understanding.

Here's the example: Solve $\frac{dy}{dx} = e^{-x^{2}}; y(3) = 5$

$$\int_{3}^{x}\frac{dy}{dt}dt = \int_{3}^{x}e^{-t^{2}}dt$$
$$ y(t)\big]_{3}^{x} = \int_{3}^{x}e^{-t^{2}}dt$$
$$\cdots$$

I'm struggling with the jump to the first step. Here's my attempt at explaining it:

We have the equation $\frac{dy}{dx} = g(x)$ with the initial condition $y(x_{0}) = y_{0}$. By the fundamental theorem of calculus, we can say

$$g(x) = \frac{d}{dx}\int_{a}^{x}g(t)dt$$

$$\rightarrow \frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{d}{dx}\int_{a}^{x}g(t)dt$$

$$\rightarrow \frac{d}{dx}y(x) = \frac{d}{dx}\int_{a}^{x}g(t)dt$$

Intuitively, I then see that we can just "cancel" the $dx$ on either side in the denominators, and then we're just left with

$$dy(x) = d\int_{a}^{x}g(t)dt$$

and we can "integrate" both sides, to get

$$y(x) = \int_{a}^{x}g(t)dt + y_{0}$$

But my intuition feels really really sketchy here, and I'd really like to understand the more rigorous steps the way a more experienced mathematician might. Would someone be able to explain the gaps?

Comment: As you said in the title, it's simply the fundamental theorem of calculus.

Comment: So I'm not missing any major gaps? I've been reviewing the FTC, but don't feel like I have as comfortable a grasp of it as I would like. So I'm just overthinking it?

Comment: Yes, there is no major gap. But there is some redundancy in your proof: we may simply write $\int_a^x g(t)dt=y(x)-(a)$ by FTC since $g=y'$ and then obtain the desired result.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out! Should I remove this post now that it's been answered?